# How can I handle an exception for a missing key in the *. properties file?

Tags: java, exception, properties

For starters, i'm new in Java.

I'm trying to get the property key or, if key's not found, get an exception.

```
Enumeration<Object> enumeration = properties.keys();

System.out.print("Enter the key name: ");
String getProp = bufferedReader.readLine();
String keys = null;

while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    keys = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
    if (!getProp.equals(keys)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("KEY IN " + name + ".properties FILE NOT FOUND");
    }
}
```

But for some reason i get the exception even if the key is exist.

What am i doing wrong? Again, i'm newbee in Java, so don't hit me so hard, please.

Maybe this entry

```
!getProp.equals(keys)
```

is incorrect in Java? I don't know what is 'not equals' analog in Java.

Comment: I moved this block (with throw new exception in it) after the while loop. Same thing, nothing has changed for some reason.

Comment: Can you show me your updated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception will be thrown if the very first key in the enumeration isn't the right key, so you need to throw it after the while loop is over.

```
Enumeration<Object> enumeration = properties.keys();

System.out.print("Enter the key name: ");
String getProp = bufferedReader.readLine();
String keys = null;

boolean foundKey = false;
while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    keys = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
    if (getProp.equals(keys)) {
        foundKey = true;
        break;
    }
}

//only throw the exception when you've tried every single key
if (!foundKey) throw new IllegalArgumentException("KEY IN " + name + ".properties FILE NOT FOUND");
```